# List of parents objects and their children with fewer queries

Tags: python, django, query-optimization, django-queryset

I've got a Django view that I'm trying to optimise.  It shows a list of parent objects on a page, along with their children.  The child model has the foreign key back to the parent, so `select_related` doesn't seem to apply.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

A naive implementation uses *n+1* queries, where *n* is the number of parent objects, ie. one query to fetch the parent list, then one query to fetch the children of each parent.

I've written a view that does the job in two queries - one to fetch the parent objects, another to fetch the related children, then some Python (that I'm far too embarrassed to post here) to put it all back together again.

Once I found myself importing the standard library's `collections` module I realised that I was probably doing it wrong.  There is probably a much easier way, but I lack the Django experience to find it.  Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to the foreign key, then use the [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method which added to Django 1.4:

> Returns a `QuerySet` that will automatically retrieve, in a single
>   batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.
>
> This has a similar purpose to `select_related`, in that both are
>   designed to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by
>   accessing related objects, but the strategy is quite different:
>
> - `select_related` works by creating a SQL join and including the fields
>     of the related object in the `SELECT` statement. For this reason,
>     `select_related` gets the related objects in the same database query.
>     However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from
>     joining across a 'many' relationship, `select_related` is limited to
>     single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
> - `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
>     relationship, and does the 'joining' in Python. This allows it to
>     prefetch many-to-many and **many-to-one objects**, which cannot be done
>     using `select_related`, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one
>     relationships that are supported by `select_related`. It also supports
>     prefetching of `GenericRelation` and `GenericForeignKey`.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children') 


>>> Parent.objects.all().prefetch_related('children')
```

All the relevant children will be fetched in a single query, and used
to make QuerySets that have a pre-filled cache of the relevant
results. These QuerySets are then used in the `self.children.all()`
calls.

> **Note 1** that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously
>   cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query.
>
> **Note 2** that if you use `iterator()` to run the query, `prefetch_related()` calls will be ignored since these two
>   optimizations do not make sense together.

Comment: I've read the Django docs you're quoting there.  While `prefetch_related` seems to do what I'm after, applying it to my query didn't change the number of queries - perhaps I'm doing it wrong...  Could you provide an example call?

Comment: Just checked in my project similar case - is executed exactly 2 request. Most likely the problem is, how do you select children from their parents. You can not use `filter` method. This leads to a new request. Use `parent.children.all()`

Comment: Also, from doc: Note that if you use `iterator()` to run the query, `prefetch_related()` calls will be ignored since these two optimizations do not make sense together.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble getting your example to work, but finally managed it by adding a `related_name` to the foreign key.  I'll edit your answer for future reference.  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you ever need to work with more than 2 levels at once, you can consider a different approach to storing trees in db using [MPTT](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt)

In a nutshell, it adds data to your model which are updated during updates and allow a much more efficient retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, select_related is what you are looking for. select_related creates a JOIN so that all the data that you need is fetched in one statement. prefetch_related runs all the queries at once then caches them.

**The trick here is to "join in" only what you absolutely need to in order to reduce the performance penalty of the join.** "What you absolutely need to" is the long way of saying that you should pre-select only the fields that you will read later in your view or template. There is good documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

This is a snippet from one of my models where I faced a similar problem:

```
return QuantitativeResult.objects.select_related(
                'enrollment__subscription__configuration__analyte', 
                'enrollment__subscription__unit', 
                'enrollment__subscription__configuration__analyte__unit',
                'enrollment__subscription__lab',
                'enrollment__subscription__instrument_model'
                'enrollment__subscription__instrument',
                'enrollment__subscription__configuration__method',
                'enrollment__subscription__configuration__reagent',
                'enrollment__subscription__configuration__reagent__manufacturer',
                'enrollment__subscription__instrument_model__instrument__manufacturer'
                ).filter(<snip, snip - stuff edited out>)
```

In this pathological case, I went down from 700+ queries to just one. The django debug toolbar is your friend when it comes to this sort of issue.

Comment: That's an impressive query reduction!  But does `select_related` allow following a foreign key in the 'reverse' direction?  (I agree that django debug toolbar is a invaluable tool...)

Comment: I was not able to follow a FK in the reverse direction. In one troublesome case, I had to fall back to raw SQL ( with the attendant loss of portability )